# Sub Grouping set of rows based on a condition

Tags: sql

My requirement is a bit tricky,

I have an item which gets transferred between the groups, persons.
I wanted to calculate the mis transfers happened with that item, who did and when did it happen [Attaching the source table data for one item, along with the output which am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FivaF.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read the guides on [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) in order to better understand you and provide you with even better answers.

Comment: `[Attaching…` seems to have failed.